# What is consuming ZFS pool space?

Tags: filesystems, solaris, zfs, oracle-12c

Environment:

- SP firmware 3.2.4.1
- zfs
- Solaris 11 zones

Problem:

Poor system design has lead to constant space pressure on the internal disks.
Once a pool goes over 80%, zfs goes into a whole lock down state.
Many of my zones sit on top of the same pool so any zone could be what causes the problem and it takes hours to look in directories for file(s) that are safe to delete.

Example...

`zpool list`:

```
NAME         SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CAP  DEDUP     HEALTH  ALTROOT
myzone       556G   475G  80.5G  90%  1.00x     ONLINE  -
```

`df -h`:

```
myzone/zone1/rpool/ROOT/solaris-8/var   547G   7.8G        72G    10%    /zones2/zone1/root/var
myzone/zone2/rpool/ROOT/solaris-11      547G   6.2G        72G     8%    /zones2/zone2/root
myzone/zone3/rpool/ROOT/solaris-11      547G   6.2G        72G     8%    /zones2/zone3/root
myzone/zone4/rpool/ROOT/solaris-11      547G   6.2G        72G     8%    /zones2/zone4/root
myzone/zone5/rpool/ROOT/solaris-11      547G   6.2G        72G     8%    /zones2/zone5/root
myzone/zone6/rpool/ROOT/solaris-11      547G   6.2G        72G     8%    /zones2/zone6/root
myzone/zone7/rpool/ROOT/solaris-11      547G   6.2G        72G     8%    /zones2/zone7/root
myzone/zone8/rpool/ROOT/solaris-11      547G   6.2G        72G     8%    /zones2/zone8/root
myzone/zone9/rpool/ROOT/solaris-11      547G   6.2G        72G     8%    /zones2/zone9/root
myzone/zone10/rpool/ROOT/solaris-11     547G   6.2G        72G     8%    /zones2/zone10/root
```

Question:

What is the quickest way via command or script to find what is consuming the space?  How do I find if it is one big file or thousands of little files consuming space?  Which zone is the problem?

Comment: `df` is mostly worthless when it comes to zfs.  What happens if you `zfs list`?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `zfs list -t all` — that shows all the filesystems and snapshots, and should give you a *lot* of insight into what is consuming space. To remove things, use `zfs destroy fs[@snap]`.

That’s the common case. For the uncommon cases check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43249145/823872